# Thomson TG782T ADSL2+ modem loses network connection

Tags: 10.04, network-manager

I am using an ubuntu 10.04 server (running on a Lenovo Thinkpad notebook) as my webserver. It is performing well in terms of handling the traffic etc. However my internet connection is ADSL2+ (using Thomson TG782T modem-router) and if the modem is reset, then my server loses network connection. The networkmanager icon shows a red exclamation mark showing that is has no connection. But as soon as I click on it and tell it to connect to eth0, the connection is back on.

It must be something that networkmanager is failing to do and because of this, the reliability of my webserver is suffering. Any advice on how this can be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there's no way to have it auto reconnect when the connection is coming back up. But there are some "custom" solutions out there, like [this python script](http://best-ubuntu-notebook.blogspot.com/2010/12/network-manager-auto-reconnect-solved.html) for example.